# Where is the tool for password encryption in 12.04?

Tags: password, encryption, seahorse, tools

Ubuntu at Launchpad tells me to set up pgp keys by going to the **Passwords and Encryption Keys** tool. However I cannot find this program anyplace. In addition info is sparce on the net about Ubuntu's "Passwords and Encryption Keys tool."  How to get it or find it?

Comment: I guess it is called **SEAHORSE** , try from Ubuntu software center or Synaptic. It is already present as password and keys.

Comment: @tijybba You should post that as an answer, with a screenshot maybe? :)

Comment: Thanks @nitstorm but this [official page](https://help.launchpad.net/YourAccount/ImportingYourPGPKey)  seems to explain it all.

Comment: @tijybba Your answer could also link to that page, summarizing the main points and explaining briefly what Seahorse is (perhaps with a screenshot as nitstorm suggested).

Answer (score 2):

I am posting it from [here](https://launchpad.net/+help-registry/openpgp-keys.html#publish) ,and [here](https://help.launchpad.net/YourAccount/ImportingYourPGPKey) with some screen-shots..

Now from the **Dash** search Bar , Either type **Seahorse** or **Password and Keys** and click to launch it.

**Creating the key in Ubuntu**

**Step 1**  To create new key , press **Ctrl+N** or the **+** button as shown in image. It will list keys if already added.

[image]

**Step 2** Select the **PGP key** option and continue.

[image]

**Step 3** You will be asked to Enter details as in Image , add the Details seriously as **Email Address** you used for **Launchpad** . Keep the Encryption type **RSA** by default , and **Expiration date** to **Never Expires** *( you can change it anytime from the **Step 4** menu).*

[image]

After filling the fields , the **Create** Button will be **Active** and will take you to this image, showing the progress of **Generating Key** .

[image]

**Step 4** After creating the key it will be listed in **Step 1** Image , right click to **properties** , it will bring up image like this , showing the generated Key and Other Information

[image]

**Step 5** Now you need to **SYNC** your key to **Ubuntu keyserver** , for that select the key as in **Step 1** and from **Menu** bar ,select  **Remote >> Sync and Publish Keys**. Which will show this image. By default in Ubuntu keyservers are already present , you don't need to add anything , just select thee **SYNC** option to sync with keyservers.

[image]

It can take up to **thirty minutes** before your key is available to Launchpad *(so it is advised to wait)*. After that time, you're ready to import key into into Launchpad.

Now to **Import the key in Launchpad** , copy the Ten Blocks of **Fingerprint** from 
**Step 3** Select the Fingerprint text code *(the ten blocks of numbers and letter)*. Copy the text by pressing the Ctrl+c keys together.

**Or** Alternately You can retrieve the key using the **GPG command** *(yours will be different from below :D)*

Open a terminal and enter:

```
gpg --fingerprint
```

GPG will display a message similar to:

```
pub 1024D/12345678 2007-01-26
Key fingerprint = 0464 39CD 2486 190A 2C5A 0739 0E68 04DC 16E7 CB72
Geoffrey Hayes (My OpenPGP key) <geoffrey@bungle.com>
sub 2048g/ABCDEF12 2007-01-26
```

Highlight and copy only the numeric fingerprint: **0464 39CD 2486 190A 2C5A 0739 0E68 04DC 16E7 CB72** in the example above. And paste it to **Import an OpenPGP key** option in your Launchpad account.

Launchpad will send e-mail to you  with instructions on finishing the process.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 12.04, you can open Passwords and Keys by opening your Unity Dash (by clicking the Ubuntu icon in the top left corner, or by typing the Windows key on your keyboard). This will open your Dash with a search box. In that box, type "passwords" and the application icon will appear. Click the Passwords and Keys icon, and from there you can create your PGP key by going to "File", then "New", then chosing "PGP Key".

For additional information, please read through [Ubuntu Wiki - GNU Privacy Guard](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/GnuPrivacyGuardHowto)
 on how to generate an OpenPGP key.